# How to programmatically add a function to an Object like the following example

Tags: javascript, object, methods

How to programmatically add an Object method like the following example.

```js
let object2 = {
  name: "object2",

  onExecute() {
    const input1 = this.getInputData(0)
    // do something
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically add a method to the object. I need to end up with the object2 example.

I tried the following, but it does not seem to be correct.

```js
object2.onExecute = () => {
    const input1 = this.getInputData(0)
    // do something
  }
```

Comment: One is an arrow function which will have the enclosing `this` value (not `object1`) the other a method shorthand syntax where `this` will be `object2` if called as `object2.onExecute()`.

Comment: "*Will there be any differences when they execute?*" why didn't you try them? You'd have found out immediately.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for the explanation. This has been helpful.

Comment: @VLAZ, I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically add a method to the object. I need to end up with the object2 example.

Comment: Then you should probably ask a question about that specifying what you've tried and what you expect the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did this:

```js
object2.onExecute = function () {
  const input1 = this.getInputData(0)
  // do something
}
```

and it worked as expected.